# Concatenating Two Columns in Pandas Using the Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have three Pandas data frames consisting of the id of patients being used as their index, and time series values of different patients in order of their time of measurement. All of these patients have the same number of measurements (there are two values for each patient). I want to create a third data frame which just concatenates these data frames. Catch: Not all patients are represented in all data frames. The final data frame should contain only the patients represented in ALL three data frames. An example for the data frames (please note there's three in total):

A

| id | value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 |
| 1 | 78 |
| 2 | 76 |
| 2 | 79 |

B

| id | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 65 |
| 2 | 67 |
| 3 | 74 |
| 3 | 65 |

```py
# to reproduce the data frames
df1 =pd.DataFrame({"stay_id":[2,2,3,3], "value":[65,67,74,65]})
df2 =pd.DataFrame({"stay_id":[1,1,2,2],"value":[80,78,76,79]})
```

What I'm trying to create:

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 76 | 65 |
| 2 | 79 | 67 |

I tried:

```py
data = pd.merge(A, B, on="stay_id")
```

But the result is:

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 76 | 65 |
| 2 | 76 | 67 |
| 2 | 79 | 65 |
| 2 | 79 | 67 |

So the first value gets repeated along the axis. I also tried:

```py
complete = A.copy()
complete["B" = B["value2"]
```

Does this ensure the values being matched for the id?

Comment: Can you post your dataframes as dicts, so we can recreate your issue?

Comment: What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? PS Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: The site is a repository of good Q&A. Please edit your question to be the best it can be. That means, no matter what is or isn't in some answer.

Comment: @aegis301 No problem. I see you have update your question, what you want does not have much sense to me, except if you have a field that is unique for each entry in the tables so that can be merge. I dont know if i explain my self, but what I mean with this is: why the value 76 from table 1 only match with 65 in table 2 but not with 67. are these different entries of different test? do you have other columns so that you can make a unique_id to merge the data?

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte again I am sorry I did not clarify this: There are multiple measurements of values for a patient. One could be e.g. the heart rate, one could be the mean blood pressure. There is a fixed number of measurements to fixed times, to be exact: 48 measurements per variable in the real data set. I am trying to create a data frame that contains ONLY the the patients that have BOTH heart rate and blood pressure and where the nth row for a patient contains the nth heart rate and nth blood pressure measurement.

Comment: @aegis301 Final question, is the time one of your columns? Now I get what you want to do

Comment: Time is not one of my columns. However It is guaranteed that each value has the same number of measurements

Answer (score 0):

I modify the answer according to the comments exchanged in the question, you need to find a unique identifier to merge from; since you have the number of measurements, this is "n_meassurement" and "stay_id", consider, for example, the following modification of the dataframes:

```py
df1 =pd.DataFrame({"stay_id":[2,2,3,3], "value":[65,67,74,65],
                   "number_measurement":["measurement_1", "measurement_2", "measurement_1", "measurement_2" ]})
df2 =pd.DataFrame({"stay_id":[1,1,2,2],"value":[80,78,76,79], 
                  "number_measurement":["meassurement_1", "measurement_2", "measurement_1", "measurement_2" ]})

output = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["stay_id", "number_measurement"])
print(output)
```

Output:

```
    stay_id     value_x     number_measurement  value_y
0     2            65         measurement_1       76
1     2            67         measurement_2       79
```

now just drop the column number_measurement:

```py
output.drop("number_measurement", axis=1)

    stay_id     value_x     value_y
0      2          65          76
1      2          67          79
```

Comment: I'm sorry I might missed a clarification here, I'm trying to concatenate along axis 1, so I want to keep the columns as is but combine them into a single data frame

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, first start by making the dataframes have the same columns names by using [**`pandas.DataFrame.set_axis`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) and then, concatenate those dataframes with the help of [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). Finally, use a boolean mask to keep only the rows with an `id` figuring in all the dataframes.

Considering there is a third dataframe (called `dfC`), you can try the code below :

| id | value3 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 72 |
| 2 | 83 |
| 4 | 78 |
| 4 | 76 |

```
list_df = [dfA, dfB, dfC]
out = pd.concat([df.set_axis(['id', 'value'], axis=1) for df in list_df], ignore_index=True)
out = out[out.id.isin(list(set.intersection(*(set(df["id"]) for df in list_df))))]
```

###### `>>> print(out)`

```
   id  value
2   2     76
3   2     79
4   2     65
5   2     67
8   2     72
9   2     83
```

Comment: I'm sorry I missed an opportunity to clarify here: I want to keep the columns as is, and concatenate along axis=1, so both columns are side by side, matching the stay_id as index. I adjusted my question accordingly for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying I finally found a way using some of @Lucas M. Uriarte's logic, thanks a lot for that!

```py
df1 =pd.DataFrame({"stay_id":[2,2,3,3], "value":[65,67,74,65]})
df2 =pd.DataFrame({"stay_id":[1,1,2,2],"value":[80,78,76,79]})

df1_patients = set(df1.index.values)
df2_patients = set(df2.index.values)

patients = set.intersection(df1, df2)
patients = list(patients)

reduced_df1 = df1.loc[patients]
reduced_df2 = df2.loc[patients]

reduced_df1.sort_index(inplace=True)
reduced_df2.sort_index(inplace=True)

data = reduced_df1.copy()
data["value2"] = reduced_df2["value2"]
```

This as far as I can see it ensures keeping only the entries that are in both data frames and matches the values row by row in this scenario.

Comment: aegis301 I have modified my answer following the comments. let me know if works